# Why v-for won't render any DOMs? 'Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.'

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I would like to render several div containers depending on a returned API call from axios/vue. The axios call and callback work just fine, but vue won't render any divs.

Since I am using Django, I already changed the delimiters from curly brackets (which is Django default as well).

***Error message in console:***

```
Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. 
Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, 
or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

Please find a minimal code snippet as follows (if you remove the JS part the html will show up):

Thank you in advance for your help!

```js
var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '.EUR_Quotes',
  data: {
    info: []
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=XXXd&base=EUR")
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data.rates;
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
});
```

```css
.EUR_Quotes {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
 <body>
    
    <div v-for="rates in info">
    <div class="EUR_Quotes">[[ data ]]
    </div>
    </div>
    
 </body>
  
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing your data variable name, it should be `info` in your template, (not `data`) the actual `data` object is the container for all your `vuejs` app's data.

Check the snippet, it works fine.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '.EUR_Quotes',
  data: {
    info: []
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=d&base=EUR")
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data.rates;
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
});
```

```css
.EUR_Quotes {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
 <body>
    
    <div v-for="rates in info">
    <div class="EUR_Quotes">[[ info ]]
    </div>
    </div>
    
 </body>
  
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  
</html>
```

Comment: much appreciated!